# Power Apps - Dashboard Display Sequence

Tags: powerapps

On Power Apps, I have a dashboard to display all orders made by users. The dashboard is to let users know their order status either their order is  in "In Preparation", "Order Received" or "Completed" status. I am using SharePoint List as the data source. Below is the dashboard I have created.

[image]

There are two conditions that I like the dashboard to follow.

Order Date & Time: The latest order made by user will lead the flow of the menu on the dashboard screen. In this case, SMT 1 is the first order created by users and in SPL. Thus, dashboard will display the order made by SMT 1 first.
Order Urgency: There are two levels of order urgency: Normal and Urgent. In this case, Urgent orders will override the order in first condition. For example, SMT 3 and SMT 4 orders. Even though SMT 3 made the order ahead than SMT 4, I would like the dashboard gives the priority to SMT 4 and display SMT 4 orders first, followed by SMT 3.

I am using gallery and container to make the dashboard anyway.

I`d appreciate if any of you guys could lend me some help and show me guidance on the solution to this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: This seems to be as simple as ordering by `Order Urgency DESC, OrderDate DESC`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid DESC as in Descending? I am new to Power Apps anyway.

Comment: Yes, descneding. The concept applies equally for any data, i.e. excel as well. Plug some dummy data into excel and try ordering by those columns in that order

Comment: What is the formula used in `items` property of the gallery control?

Comment: Also, what is the column/data type of Order Urgency column, choice or single line of text?

Comment: @GaneshSanap Items property of the gallery is the SPL name. And the data type for Urgency is single line of text.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid In order to do that, I need to make it descending at the list settings, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `SortByColumns()` function in Power Apps for such requirements.

For example, you can use the formula like below:

```
SortByColumns(
    SPListName,
    "OrderUrgency",
    SortOrder.Descending,
    "OrderDateTime",
    SortOrder.Ascending
)
```

Where `OrderUrgency` and `OrderDateTime` are the internal names of your SharePoint list columns. You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Comment: Do I configure this at Item property of the gallery?

Comment: Yes items property of gallery Control.

Comment: It`s not working. It still follows the arrangement in SPL which is by OrderDateTime column. Do I need to do anything at SPL?

Comment: Can you show us the complete formula you are using? Make sure you are using correct internal names of the columns. Also, try adding indexing on both order date-time and order urgency columns: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/add-an-index-to-a-list-or-library-column-f3f00554-b7dc-44d1-a2ed-d477eac463b0

Comment: That`s okey. It`s already working. I made a mistake where I did not use correct internal names. Thank you so much for your help, I appreciate it!

Comment: Hi, so I did another test run for the dashboard. I placed three orders at the same time (Normal, Urgent, Normal). Supposedly the Urgent one will be displayed first however it still follows the order flow I made. Here's the code that I used."field_0" is OrderDateTime column and "field_2" is Urgency column in Order Summary SPL. `SortByColumns(
    'Order Summary',
    "field_0",
    SortOrder.Descending,
    "field_2",
    SortOrder.Descending
)`

Comment: Check formula in my answer carefully. First you have to add the Field_2 and then field_0. Also, try using Ascending order For date and time.

Comment: I already changed the column arrangement, nothing happened. And I used Descending order for DateTime because I want to show the recent order placed based from my SPL on my dashboard. In my SPL, recent orders were at the bottom of the list. Not at the top.